# Operator norm of difference of operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Given two positive operators $P_1(\cdot)$ and $P_2(\cdot)$ for matrix $X\in R^{m\times n}$, where the positiveness means that
\begin{align}
\langle P(X), X \rangle \ge 0, \forall X.
\end{align}
Define the operator norm:
\begin{align}
\| P\|_{op}=\sup_{\|X\|_F\le1} \| P(X)\|_F.
\end{align}

Then, is the following correct?
\begin{align}
\| P_1 - P_2\|_{op}\le \max \{\| P_1\|_{op} ,\| P_2\|_{op} \}
\end{align}

Comment: If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are symmetric the conclusion holds.